# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type NoneType)

Tags: python, object-detection, numpy-ndarray, tensor, mediapipe

I am working on my project of Sign Language Recognition after completely training my model I just need to run real time detection but there comes an error.

I'm taking the help from the **TUTORIAL** :-

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doDUihpj6ro&t=7583s
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ui85SVJsRf8&t=603s

**MY CODE :-**

`

```
from function import *
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
json_file = open("model.json", "r")
model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(model_json)
model.load_weights("model.h5")


# 1. New detection variables
sequence = []
sentence = []
threshold = 0.4 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
# Set mediapipe model 
with mp_hands.Hands(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
    while cap.isOpened():

        # Read feed
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        # Make detections
        image, results = mediapipe_detection(frame, holistic)
        print(results)
        
        # Draw landmarks
        draw_styled_landmarks(image, results)

        # 2. Prediction logic
        keypoints = extract_keypoints(results)
        sequence.append(keypoints)
        sequence = sequence[-51:]

        if len(sequence) == 51:
                res = model.predict(np.expand_dims(sequence, axis=0))[0]
                print(actions[np.argmax(res)])

        # Show to screen
        cv2.imshow('OpenCV Feed', image)

        # Break gracefully
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord(' '):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**ERROR :::-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Project\Sign Language Detection\newapp.py", line 40, in <module>
    res = model.predict(np.expand_dims(sequence, axis=0))[0]
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type NoneType).
```

..........
..........